# Upload images To website PHP

Tags: php

Saw this code on a tutorial and worked for him but dont work for me, my code is:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
//$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
//$type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
if (isset($name)){
$location = 'images/uploads/';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$name,$location);
}
```

and the form is:

```
<form method="post" class="pure-form" action="createTeam.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="logo">Team Logo:</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="file" >
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button button-secondary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Do I do the php in the same page as the form or I do it in a different page?
And why am I gettin the error `Notice: Undefined index: file` ?
Please help.

Comment: [**Read... the... manual...**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` is not correctly used.
Please refer to [PHP move_uploaded_file function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

try this:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name);
```

and make sure you have created the directory `images/uploads`.

```
Notice: Undefined index: file
```

this is not an error. It's just a notice. you can ignore it. See: [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: and the Undefined index: file error? how do I bypass it?

Comment: put this at the beginning of your code. `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);`